# How to make an SQL field that counts up if another field contains a certain value but resets to 0 based on certain value?

Tags: sql, counter

I need to make a column in SQL that counts up if a field has a certain value but the counter needs to reset to 0 if the field has another value.

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbvbn.png)

As the screenshot shows, I want to make a column that starts on 1 and it counts up if the value of the event_type is 'CREATE'. If the value of event_type is 'CREATE' two times in a row, then I need the counter to become 2.

If the value of event_type is 'DELETE' then I need the counter to reset to 0.

I need the counter to be specific for for each combination of different customer_id and property_id.

Please let me know if you need further information from me.

Thank you!

Comment: You should include the full schema for the table in question (e.g. an auto-increment column could make this much easier), and you should specify the type of sql you are using (sqlite?)

Comment: I am using Google BigQuery.

I am not sure what you mean by the full schema of the table? I can create an auto-increment column by using ROW_NUMBER() if required but I am not sure what would be the next step to achieve the desired output?

Comment: My basic idea would be that you would set the value of `rowN` to `row(N-1) + 1`, with a `CASE` to check if the value is `DELETE` (and thus setting to `0` instead). I'm unfamiliar with BigQuery aside from it being standard ansi sql, but by "schema" I mean the columns in use within your table(s), and any indices involved.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text